# A specific example about computing of curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

After learned some Riemann Geometry, I want to compute the curvature of $S^2$ by the way of Riemann curvature.

So, I assume the $S^2$ is 
$$
(\theta_1,\theta_2)\rightarrow (\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2,\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2,\cos\theta_2)
$$
Then,
$$
 g_{11}=\sin^2\theta_2  \\
 g_{22}=1  ~~~~~~~~~
$$
Then
$$
\Gamma_{11}^2=-\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2  \\
\Gamma_{12}^1=\Gamma_{21}^1=\frac{\cos\theta_2}{\sin\theta_2}
$$
Then,......

I think if by the way ,it's very hard for computing the curvature of n-sphere of  $r$-radius

So, I want to know what is the easy way to compute the curvature, at least, the easy way to compute the curvature of $S^n(r)$ (radius is $r$).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409092/riemann-ricci-curvature-tensor-and-ricci-scalar-of-the-n-dimensional-sphere