# Difference between second fundamental form of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and of $M$ as a boundary.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

How do I compute the second fundamental form and mean curvature of a boundary?

For example, if we consider the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ as a boundary of the hemisphere $\mathbb{S}^{n+1}$ with the spherical metric. Will the second fundamental form and mean curvature be different than that of $\mathbb{S}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

I would like to see a worked example of these computation. I couldn't find it anywhere. Could show references?

Answer (score 3):

I am lazy to write up calculations, so let us take a look at the picture below.

[image: embeddings of the sphere]

Your first example (on the left) is an equatorial embedding of $\mathbb{S}^n$ into the standard embedding of $\mathbb{S}^{n+1}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ (the round sphere). Try to convince yourself that the Gauss map is constant, and therefore the derivative of the unit normal vanishes identically. Such embeddings are called *totally geodesic*. You can learn more in the textbooks, or from [this](http://www.boma.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/data/49print.pdf) article (H.-B. Rademacher, Totally geodesic submanifold - definition).

In the second example, on the right, the Gauss map of the depicted embedding of $\mathbb{S}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is not constant, so the derivative does not vanish. A hint to a calculation is given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141245/2002). This is an example of a *totally umbilic* embedding, by the way.

I hope that my answer will help you to recover accurate calculations.

**Quiz.** What is wrong with the right picture?

For the curious: I've just made this picture by hand in Inskcape with LaTeX formula extension.

Comment: But, what if it is not a great circle? Like any other latitude?

Comment: @Alice you could draw a picture yourself, or just use imagination to see that the Gauss map won't be constant in that case.

Comment: @Alice I think the key is to understand the normal vector is different in two cases, in first case the normal vector of $S^n$ which is normal to $S^n$ but still in the tangent space of $S^{n+1}$, so that's why it stays same in different point, if it is not great circle, the normal vectors will change direction ( "pointing north")